# Python string to int/float [pandas/web scraping with BeautifulSoup]

Tags: python, pandas

I have question that I could not find an answer on the web for this
I have some Dataframe which I created from some web scraping

in my Dataframe there is a column with numbers
the data there is of string type which need to be converted to int,
the problem is that the string is : **\n 3,155\n**
and it need to be converted to **3155**(int or float)

I have tried that:

```
var='\n 3,155\n'

for x in var.split():
    if var.isdigit():
        int(x)
type(var)
int(var)
```

```
Error:  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n 3,155\n'
```

Comment: You can use `strip()` to get rid of the white space on the ends and `replace()` to get rid of the `,`: `int(var.strip().replace(',', ''))` --> `3155`

Comment: Can you share more of your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var = '\n 3,155\n'
var = var.strip(' \n,') #Removes spaces and newlines
var = var.replace(',', '') #"Removes" the comma

for char in var:
    print(ord(char), char)
```

Or in one line

```
var = var.replace(',', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
```

To convert the String into an Int

```
var = int(var) #Or var = float(var)
```

Comment: @SaucyGoat Well yes, but actually no

Comment: Wow,Thank you!!
worked amazing for me :

var = var.replace(',', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')